# why my code "Bouncing ball" doesn't work?

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm trying to write a code a bout a bouncing ball, but i'm stuck in how to make the ball bounced. The code seems correct, no wrong messages from eclipse and yet the ball doesn't move. Any help/hint is appreciate.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BouncingBallTest extends JFrame {

    private JButton jbtStart = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton jbtStop = new JButton("Stop");
    private Ball canvas = new Ball();

    public BouncingBallTest() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // Use the panel to group buttons
        panel.add(jbtStart);
        panel.add(jbtStop);

        add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Add canvas to centre
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Add panel to south

        // register listener
        jbtStart.addActionListener(new StartBouncingBallTest());
        jbtStop.addActionListener(new StopBouncingBallTest());

    }

    // the main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new BouncingBallTest();
        frame.setTitle("Bouncing Ball Test");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(470, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class StartBouncingBallTest implements ActionListener { // inner class
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            canvas.StartBouncingBallTest();
        }
    }

    class StopBouncingBallTest implements ActionListener { // inner class
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            canvas.StopBouncingBallTest();
        }
    }

    class Ball extends JPanel {
        private int radius = 10;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int dx = 3;
        private int dy = 3;

        private Timer timer = new Timer(20, new TimerListener());

        public void StartBouncingBallTest() {
            if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
                x += dx;
                y += dy;
            }

            else if (x == 0) {
                x -= dx;
                y += dy;
            }

            else if (y + (2 * radius) > getHeight()) {
                x += dx;
                y -= dy;
            }

            else if (y == 0) {
                x += dx;
                y -= dy;
            }

            else if (x + (2 * radius) > getWidth()) {
                x -= dx;
                y += dy;
            }
            repaint();

            timer.start();

        }

        public void StopBouncingBallTest() {

            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

        }
    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your timer action does not modify the coordinates at all. Move the positioning code there and you should see some movement.

Comment: I tried but nothing is happened..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, nothing is moving the ball.

Each time the Swing `Timer` ticks, all you do is repaint.

You need to move the movement logic to the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` registered to the `Timer`

More like...

```
public void StartBouncingBallTest() {
    timer.start();
}

//...

class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }

        else if (x == 0) {
            x -= dx;
            y += dy;
        }

        else if (y + (2 * radius) > getHeight()) {
            x += dx;
            y -= dy;
        }

        else if (y == 0) {
            x += dx;
            y -= dy;
        }

        else if (x + (2 * radius) > getWidth()) {
            x -= dx;
            y += dy;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This way, each time the `Timer` ticks, you are making update the position of the ball accordingly...

**Updated with working example**

I made two changes.  I made your `TimerListener` an inner class of `Ball`, which allows it to access the variable and methods of `Ball` and modified your movement logic so it works

[image: Bounce]

```
class Ball extends JPanel {

    private int radius = 10;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int dx = 3;
    private int dy = 3;

    private Timer timer = new Timer(20, new TimerListener());

    public void StartBouncingBallTest() {

        timer.start();

    }

    public void StopBouncingBallTest() {

        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (x < 0 || x + (2 * radius) > getWidth()) {
                dx *= -1;
            }
            if (y < 0 || y + (2 * radius) > getHeight()) {
                dy *= -1;
            }

            x += dx;
            y += dy;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right..it does. I had a wrong placement of a brace when i tried first your method. To make "TimerListener an inner class of Ball"..i'have (never) thought to it!!..and Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Timer timer = new Timer(20, new TimerListener());
```

doesn't that `new TimerListener()` need to do something useful?  shouldn't most of the code inside `StartBouncingBallTest` be happening every time the timer ticks, intsead of just once when the timer starts?

Comment: Yes, but that's only half the problem.  If that code were run repeatedly, the ball would move to (-3, 3) and then get stuck.  So this won't solve the OP's issue.

Comment: well, the op's original problem was that nothing was happening.  that would be not nothing, and hopefully let the OP troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 0):

you never declared that the g.fillOval was the ball here do this...

```
g.drawOval((int)applex, (int)appley, (int)appleradius, appleradius);
  public double applex = ArandomX; //replace the random with values..
    public double appley = ArandomY; //same here
    public int appleradius = 10;
```

this makes it move...

```
a.px += a.vx;
        // check for boundaries
        if (a.px >= this.getWidth() || a.px <= 0) {
            // reverse vel and apply
            a.vx = -a.vx;
            a.px += -a.vx; // to prevent sticking
        }

        //a.vx += -gravity; // add this constant to accelerate things down
        a.py += a.vy;
        // check for boundaries
        if (a.py >= this.getHeight() || a.py <= 0) {
            // reverse vel and apply
            a.vy = -a.vy;
            a.py += a.vy; // to prevent sticking
        }`
```

replace a.vx with your x or dx idk because your variables are unclear and yeah just replace a.vy with  either y or dy and do the same for my px... it will work

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the random with values.."? and what's a?

Comment: What does "your x or dx idk" mean?  That last sentence is incomprehensible.